# Fur not moving with rigged main mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

So i created this bear model with fur and rigged it but when i pose it only the bear´s base mesh moves and not the fur. i can´t find what to do anywhere. Need help please!

This is what it looks like:

[image: Weird bear looking stuff]

[image: Rendered Bear]

[image: Posed]

Answer (score 3):

You have to move the particles modifier to the bottom of the modifiers stack, this way the particle system will use the modified mesh from the previous modifiers:

[image]

**Note:**
also there is an option on the particle system tab to use the modifiers stack ( but I don't think it does anything ? )

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!! It worked. didn´t think i would get an answer.