# Unable to render pose ? ( Ive rigged my mesh, changed its pose and now it does not display in the render )

Tags: rendering, rigging, particles, rigify

Ive created a 3d basic human mesh, and ive added a particle system to it. Ive then rigged the mesh using riggify and have now posed it. However when i go to render this, it displays the previous 't-pose'.
Im really stuck and would love help asap as im really desperate, thankyou all!

In the picture below the left picture is my desired pose, and on the  right is there rendered result.

[image]

Comment: Did you check that you didn't de-activate your armature modifier for render ? Please post a screenshot of your modifier tab.

Comment: apply the armature, and the particle system will work from the applied mesh data. However, once  you apply the armature, you won't be able to pose your character again. (I recommend duplicating your rig, and applying the duplicate, so you can still pose the first one later if you need to.)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the reply, im really new to blender so im not sure how to apply the armature.
where do i find the armature modifier ? sorry for my lack of knowledge! Thankyou so much

Comment: It'll be the order of your modifiers https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34262/fur-not-moving-with-rigged-main-mesh